# RewriteRule maps domain to external IP which is not known internally

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have made a RewriteRule set which is working with internal IP-address, but not with the external IP-address/Domain. I get '...No route to host: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 83.136.91.105:80 (*) failed'. Rule not working:

```
RewriteRule   ^/fundogfortidsminder$  /fundogfortidsminder/ [R,NC]
RewriteRule   ^/fundogfortidsminder/$  /fundogfortidsminder/jsp/forside.jsp [P,NC]

http://ff.gis34.dk/fundogfortidsminder is not working
http://192.168.255.48/fundogfortidsminder working (ip within my local network)
```

Is there a way to specify in the Apache script, that will force Apache to us the local IP address when reciving requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve the issue by adding my domain in the /etc/hosts

```
192.168.255.48     ff.gis34.dk      ff.gis34.dk
```